# What's the issue with following code snippet?

Tags: php

The PHP code is as follows:

```
if($duration!='' && $duration_in_hrs!='') {
    $duration_in_sec = $duration_in_hrs * 60 * 60;
    //echo $grid->mSqlArr['where']; die;
    if(empty($grid->mSqlArr['where']) && $grid->mSqlArr['where']=='')
        $grid->mSqlArr['where'] = " tests.test_duration = "."'"$duration"'"." ".$duration_in_sec;
    else 
        $grid->mSqlArr['where']  .= " AND tests.test_duration "."'"$duration"'"." ".$duration_in_sec;
}
```

If I comment the code from line no. 4 to 7 and echo the value of variable `$grid->mSqlArr['where']` it's printing the output  `is_test_cancled='0' AND is_test_archive='0'`
 But when I remove the comments and run the code the blank screen appears, I can't get how this is happening. I tried to debug, during that I got the following error
**PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in view_tests.php on line 218
Errors parsing view_tests.php**

Can you help me in resolving this error. I didn't get after having value how the variable can be unrecognized? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which of the lines of code that you posted is line 218?

Comment: @AndyLester: The line no.218 is following:
$grid->mSqlArr['where'] = " tests.test_duration = "."'"$duration"'"." ".$duration_in_sec;

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting is a dead giveaway. Check the following line (and the one two below it in your original code snippet):

```
$grid->mSqlArr['where'] = " tests.test_duration = "."'"$duration"'"." ".$duration_in_sec;
```

You have a string - `" tests.test_duration = "."'"` and then after it you have a variable `$duration` and then another string `"'"." ".$duration_in_sec`.

If you're meaning to concatenate them all together into one string, you should add the `$duration` into the string, eg.

```
$grid->mSqlArr['where'] = " tests.test_duration = "."'".$duration."'"." ".$duration_in_sec;
```

(note the extra `.`s around the `$duration` variable)

Answer (score 0):

You are building your strings wrong

```
$grid->mSqlArr['where'] = " tests.test_duration = "."'"$duration"'"." ".$duration_in_sec;
```

should probably be

```
$grid->mSqlArr['where'] = " tests.test_duration = '$duration' "  . $duration_in_sec;
```

although I don't know what it is that you're trying to build exactly.  But you need a `.` between each string that you are concatenating together.  Also note that you can embed variables in double-quoted strings and they will expand out.